# PHP json_encode to JS object not usable

Tags: php, javascript, json, object

I have an some PHP that looks like this:

```
$exec[0] = shell_exec("cat /etc/msm.conf | grep JAR_PATH");

$exec[1] = shell_exec("msm server list");
    if(strstr($exec[1],'[ ACTIVE ] "mc-srv" is running. Everything is OK.') !== FALSE){
        $exec[1] = 'mc online';
    }else{
        $exec[1] = 'mc offline';
    }

$exec[2] = shell_exec("sudo ts status");
    if($exec[2] == 'Server is running'){
        $exec[2] = 'ts online';
    }else{
        $exec[2] = 'ts ofline';
    }
echo json_encode($exec,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

An AJAX request gets sent to the page and the json is returned.
If I use `console.log(JSON.parse(data))` I see this in the console `Object {0: "DEFAULT_JAR_PATH="server.jar"↵", 1: "mc online", 2: "ts ofline"}` however I can not access any of its methods even if i use an associative array.

but If i create a new object and print that to the console it (in chrome atleast) looks exactly the same in terms of syntax highlighting exect I can access it via obj.method.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I don't see json_encode anywhere in your php...

Comment: _"however I can not access any of its methods"_ - apart from that not being _methods_, but simple _properties_ - what have you _tried_ to access those?

Comment: @DavidMcMullin Sorry I forgot to copy that part >.> `echo json_encode($exec,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);'.

Comment: @CBroe I have tried data.1 (as well as using ab and c in an assoc array so data.a), and data[1]. but the latter as excepted returned the character at position x thanks

Comment: D'oh! You don't want to access `data` - that's still a simple text string and nothing more - but the _parsed result_ instead, the object that `JSON.parse` returned.

Answer (score 1):

Based on how the object is being output in the console, it looks like it's being parsed okay by JSON.parse and is valid.

In which case, you should be able to access each method like this:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(data);
console.log( obj['0'] ); // returns "DEFAULT_JAR_PATH="server.jar""
console.log( obj['1'] ); // returns "mc online"
```

`obj.0` won't work in this case because the method names are numbers.